# How to unclog a pressurized filter basket?

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance, filter-basket, pressurized-basket

Our dual-wall filter basket for the Breville Barista Express appears to be clogged. [The video here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5M8miRSUzuJpMUFw6) is long but shows pulling a shot of water through the single-wall basket (fine) and then the dual-wall basket. We've been using the dual-wall basket for years now, this isn't the first time it's happened but is the first time it's stayed like this.
I've tried:

- Soaking with a Cafiza tablet
- Soaking with vinegar and baking soda
- Burning off on a gas stove
- Poking through the exit hole with Breville's included pin. It took a long time but is now clear.

Anyone have other suggestions? Or
do I    just buy a new basket?

Comment: Does your home have a water softener? If not, that may also make it worse.